# Pandas Unique Values as Columns with Counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working with pandas dataframe and trying to flip it around in a grouped output that takes the unique values and puts them as a column, and corresponding counts for each as values in the new dataframe.

Here is the starting dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('gold', 'bronze', 'silver'),
                   ('silver', 'gold', 'bronze'),
                   ('gold', 'silver', 'bronze'),
                   ('bronze', 'silver', 'gold')],
                    columns=('Canada', 'China', 'South Korea'))
df.head()

    Canada  China   South Korea
0   gold    bronze  silver
1   silver  gold    bronze
2   gold    silver  bronze
3   bronze  silver  gold
```

The desired output would be like this:

```
    nation      gold    silver  bronze
0   Canada        2          1       1
1   China         1          2       1
2   South Korea   1          1       2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`pd.value_counts`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L710)<sup>*</sup>

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).T

             bronze  gold  silver
Canada            1     2       1
China             1     1       2
South Korea       2     1       1
```

---

<sup>* I didnot find documentation of `pd.value_counts`, so, linked github link to the function.</sup>

<sup>**EDIT**: On reading source code [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) just calls `pd.value_counts`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.get_dummies` and `sum`

```
pd.get_dummies(df.T, prefix='',prefix_sep='').sum(level=0,axis=1)

Out[995]:
             bronze  gold  silver
Canada            1     2       1
China             1     1       2
South Korea       2     1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
w = df.melt()

    variable    value
0   Canada      gold
1   Canada      silver
2   Canada      gold
3   Canada      bronze
4   China       bronze
5   China       gold
6   China       silver
7   China       silver
8   South Korea silver
9   South Korea bronze
10  South Korea bronze
11  South Korea gold
```

and then:

```
pd.crosstab(w['variable'],w['value'])
```

desired result:

```
value        bronze gold    silver
variable            
Canada        1      2       1
China         1      1       2
South Korea   2      1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('gold', 'bronze', 'silver'),
               ('silver', 'gold', 'bronze'),
               ('gold', 'silver', 'bronze'),
               ('bronze', 'silver', 'gold')],
                columns=('Canada', 'China', 'South Korea')).transpose()

df.apply(pd.value_counts,axis=1)
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation as to how this code works my help